# 'Element' is not assignable to type 'ScreenComponentType<ParamListBase, "Home"> | undefined - React Navigation on React Native

Tags: react-native, types, react-navigation

I am trying to create my stack navigator using React Navigation on a React Native app.

I have my HomeTab component, which is just this code:

```
import React from 'react';
import {createNativeStackNavigator} from '@react-navigation/native-stack';
import HomeScreen from '../screens/HomeScreen';

const Stack = createNativeStackNavigator();

export const HomeTab = () => (
  <Stack.Navigator>
    <Stack.Screen name="Home" component={<HomeScreen />} />
  </Stack.Navigator>
);
```

However the component prop is highlighted as red:
[image]

With the following error:

```
 'Element' is not assignable to type 'ScreenComponentType<ParamListBase, "Home"> | undefined
```

How can I solve this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The solution is really simple.

React Navigation is not expecting an Element (JSX Expression), but rather a React Component.

To solve this, remove the < /> in the component:

```
<Stack.Screen name="Home" component={HomeScreen} />
```

Comment: what if my component takes some props for which i have to keep my component inside this </> ? 
I am new to react native and also using this package for the first time.

Comment: I am unsure, but you probably need to pass these props during the navigation action rather than in the navigator itself. Instead of using props, use navigation params and send them whenever navigating to that location.

Comment: what i found is, this:
`<Stack.Screen name="Home" component={HomeScreen} initialParams={{ param1: value }} />`

you can pass as many props you want for the component within `initialParams`